# invalid location of linked resources

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, adt

When I create a new cocos2d-x v3.0 project in OSX following this steps:

http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game

And open Eclipse->right button on project -> properties -> Resources -> Linked Resources -> Linked Resources Tab

I'm getting all folders as invalid locations:

Classes - COCOS2DX/projects/[game-name]

cocos2dx - COCOS2DX/cocos2dx

extensions - COCOS2d/extensions

scripting - COCOS2DX/scripting

[image: Screenshot of ADT window]

If I add COCOS2DX as a Path Variable with cocos2d-x root folder as in the image below, one of the files is removed from error message:

[image: Path variable COCOS@DX]

[image]

Comment: did you import the cocos2d-x lib?

Comment: Yes, i imported libcocos2dx from the [game name]/cocos2d/cocos/2d/platform/android/java

Comment: Windows? Linux? OS X?

Comment: I'm using OS X in this proj

Comment: can you post a screenshot? I setup a new project and mine is fine and I dont have any of these invalid locations

Comment: Done! I'm using cocos2d-x v3.0

Comment: so, I looked at mine and I changed them to point to the correct place. I think this is an path/environment variable issue. Let me play with it more.